# Create user in Firebase and save its data in Firestore at the same time in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 where users can create an account. Within a form, they give their names, gender, birth, etc... I would like to save this data to Firestore when a new account is created.

Right now, the account is created correctly but, the data is not being saved in Firestore.

I have tried setting the function as `async` and the call to add data to Firestore as `await` but, it didn't work. I thought that the line of save data to Firestore was being ignored.

My user model:

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  secondName: string;
  firstSurname: string;
  secondSurname: string;
  emailAddress: string;
}
```

When you finished the form and you click on Submit:

```
  onFormSubmit() {
    const password = this.personalInformation.get('password').value;

    const user: User = {
      firstName: this.personalInformation.get('firstName').value,
      secondName: this.personalInformation.get('secondName').value,
      firstSurname: this.personalInformation.get('firstSurname').value,
      secondSurname: this.personalInformation.get('secondSurname').value,
      emailAddress: this.personalInformation.get('emailAddress').value
    };

    this.authService.register(user, password)
      .then(res => {
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

The method to create the user and add the data to Firestore:

```
  register(user: User, password: string) {

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.emailAddress, password)
        .then(res => {

          Object.assign(user, {
            'dateOfCreationAccount': new Date(res.user.metadata.creationTime),
            'lastSignInTime': new Date(res.user.metadata.lastSignInTime)
          });

          // Add user to firestore
          this.firestoreService.addUser(res.user.uid, user);

          // Send verification email
          this.sendVerificationEmail();

          // Logout user
          this.logout();

          resolve(res);

        }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

The same method with `async`/`await`:

```
  register(user: User, password: string) {

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.emailAddress, password)
        .then(async res => {

          Object.assign(user, {
            'dateOfCreationAccount': new Date(res.user.metadata.creationTime),
            'lastSignInTime': new Date(res.user.metadata.lastSignInTime)
          });

          // Add user to firestore
          await this.firestoreService.addUser(res.user.uid, user);

          // Send verification email
          this.sendVerificationEmail();

          // Logout user
          this.logout();

          resolve(res);

        }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

Method to add data to Firestore:

```
  addUser(uid: string, data: User) {
    this.usersCollection.doc(uid).set(data);
  }
```

It seems that the line `this.firestoreService.addUser` is ignored. The idea is to save the user's data immediately to Firestore after creating its account.

Comment: Can you provide version where you tried to use ``async/await``?

Comment: Hi @Buczkowski, I have edited my question with your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
  addUser(uid: string, data: User) {
    this.usersCollection.doc(uid).set(data);
  }
```

to that:

```
  async addUser(uid: string, data: User) {
    await this.usersCollection.doc(uid).set(data);
  }
```

Edit 1
A bit more clarification - If you have some **Promise** and want to wait for value from that after resolve you can use **await** keyword but to use it you have to add **async** modifier to method/function and wherever you will use that you should add **await** before method/function execution. This **await** could be skipped and IDE probably warns you but to be sure that it will wait for that specific action to execute you should add **await**.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I didn't know that I need to add `async` and `await` to the other method too. So, just for clarification, if I have a `async/await` function in a service that is using another function in another service, they always need to be `async/await` in both? I thought that adding `async/await` to the first method will do all calls necessary until the original function ends. Can you explain a little bit more the reason behind?

Comment: @RRGT19 just added and I hope it will tell you something more, if not then sorry I'm not that good in explanation :)